# How do I make a command to add fraction of \textheight space?

Tags: spacing, floating-point

I would like to have a command that inserts a vertical space via

```
\myskip{.5}
```

which would be equivalent to skipping half the page.

I tried

```
\newcommand\myskip[1]{\vspace*{{#1}\textheight}}
```

But this does not work and returns a "missing number" error.

I have a style file that typesets to two different page sizes based on a switch so I don't want to just add via fixed units like cm.

I assume that the input isn't treated as a float which can be operated on.

Answer (score 3):

you have extra `{}`

```
\newcommand\myskip[1]{\vspace*{#1\textheight}}
```